# Is there a simple way to convert a pandas series to a crosstab of ratios for values in the series?

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, crosstab

**Input**

```
name    score
bob     2           
fred    4           
jim     1           
anne    5
```

**Desired Output** (ratio of scores: e.g. bob*fred in row 1 = 2/4, etc.)

```
name    bob fred    jim anne
bob     1   0.5     2   0.4
fred    2   1       4   0.8
jim     0.5 0.2     1   0.2
anne    2.5 1.25    5   1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can try outer `np.divide.outer` to compute the outer division of `score` column

```
n, s = df.to_numpy().T
pd.DataFrame(np.divide.outer(s, s), n, n)
```

---

```
      bob  fred  jim anne
bob   1.0   0.5  2.0  0.4
fred  2.0   1.0  4.0  0.8
jim   0.5  0.25  1.0  0.2
anne  2.5  1.25  5.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.corr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) to compute a custom relation function. Be aware that the diagonal is not computed but set to `1.0`.

Selecting the relevant columns is only necessary if you have more than two columns in your dataframe.

```
df[['name','score']].set_index('name').T.corr(lambda x,y: x/y)
```

Output

```
name  bob  fred  jim  anne
name                      
bob   1.0   0.5  2.0   0.4
fred  0.5   1.0  4.0   0.8
jim   2.0   4.0  1.0   0.2
anne  0.4   0.8  0.2   1.0
```

---

Dateframe to test this solution

```
import pandas as pd
import io

t = '''
name    score
bob     2           
fred    4           
jim     1           
anne    5   
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='\s+')
```

Comment: good idea of using a custom callable in correlation method +1

Comment: This is a great idea.  +1